# Setting object literal value dynamically

Tags: javascript

I know you can not set a key value dynamically, but what about the value?

I'm asking b.c. I need to know the best way to initialize an object.  Here is how I do it currently:

```
var object_pipe = {
    model : 'MUserAny',
    page  : { 
        email: '0'
    },
    args  : {
        foo : '0'
    }
};
object_pipe.args.foo = localStorage.foo;  // Statement A
```

I'd like to put statement A directly in the object literal but am not sure if it is possible or the correct syntax.

Aslo, Do I need to explicitly declare properties when I can not set them in the object literal as in here...does page need to be there?

```
var object_pipe = {
    model : 'MUserNew',
    page  : { 
    }
};
for( var key in form_elements ) {
    object_pipe.page[ form_elements[key].name ] = form_elements[key].value ;
}
```

Comment: It's just another value.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist - What does `localStorage.hash` do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly declare variables but you can just initialize the key with an empty "whatever", can be an array, string, object literal etc. You can add properties later.

```
var o = {
  a: [],
  b: {}
}

o.a[0] = 'foo'
o.b.c = 'baz'
o.d = 'pom' // New
```

Comment: right...I have to explicitly create a: ...but not a property off of a:...weird

Comment: That's right. If there's no key `f` then `o.f[0] = 'foo'` won't work.

Comment: Yes, look at `o.d = 'pom'`, there was no `d` but you just created one with string value "pom". The point here is that you can't initialize two variable types at the same time. So for `o.f = []; o.f[0] = 'baz'`

Comment: O.K sorry...I get it...object needs explicit declaration...you can't put properties on o.d

Comment: @HiroProtagonist—not that wierd. If you write `a.b = 'x'` how does the compiler know what `a` is? Is it a Function, Object, Array, Date, what? You can do conditional assignment if you know what `a` should be, something like: `if (typeof a == 'undefined') {a = [b];} else { a.push(b)}`

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with this:

```
var object_pipe = {
    model : 'MUserAny',
    page  : { 
        email: '0'
    },
    args  : {
        foo : localStorage.foo
    }
};
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XYjaX/)